# Apache does not cache my contents

Tags: apache, caching

I'm already aware of caching files with Apache. I'm writing unit tests for a library and I have one PHP file that prints the current microtime. I use it to verify if the file has changed between two requests.

My problem : the returned content is always different, even if I force caching in .htaccess with :

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
```

When I watch the response headers in the developer tools, everything seems fine :

```
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:14
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 06 Nov 2014 09:21:30 GMT
Expires:Fri, 06 Nov 2015 09:21:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.8
```